# using dot-dot-dot (`...`) with `str_replace_all()` in R

Tags: r, functional-programming, stringr, tidyeval

I have a function which is a wrapper around `stringr::str_c()`, and therefore receives any number of character vectors as input using the `...` argument.
The issue is that I would like to perform some preliminary cleaning on these vectors with `stringr::str_replace_all()` before passing them to `str_c()`, but `str_replace_all()` function only recieves a single character vector as string input.

**How do I pass `...` arguments to str_replace all()?**

Please note that I intend to use the replaced version of `...` later in my function, so the result of replacement should somehow be saved in a form that can be passed to `str_c()`.

One answer I received [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-dot-dot-dot-with-str-replace-all/162874/2?u=matanhakim) is this:

> This is inelegant, since it forces the arguments to be realized, but as you've described the issue, it gets the job done:

```
library(stringr)

f <- function(...) {
  unlist(list(...)) |> 
    str_replace_all("z", "0") |> 
    str_c()
}

f('az', 'bz', 'cz')  # "a0" "b0" "c0"
```

This indeed does the trick, but is also indeed inelegant. I would like to find a way to perform this without realizing the arguments. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a chain here i.e. `f <- function(...) {str_replace_all(c(...), 'z', '0')}` would also have given the same output `f('az', 'bz', 'cz')#
[1] "a0" "b0" "c0"`

Answer (score 2):

Use `lapply()` to map `str_replace_all()` over the captured `...`, then `do.call()` to pass all elements to `str_c()`:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all_c <- function(..., pattern, replacement) {
  list(...) |>
    lapply(str_replace_all, pattern, replacement) |>
    do.call(what = str_c)
}

v1 <- c("I_am_", "of_a_modern_")
v2 <- c("the_very_model_", "Major-General")

str_replace_all_c(v1, v2, pattern = "_", replacement = " ")
# "I am the very model "      "of a modern Major-General"
```

Using tidyverse functions, the equivalent would be:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

str_replace_all_c <- function(..., pattern, replacement) {
  dots <- map(
    list2(...),
    \(x) str_replace_all(x, pattern, replacement)
  )
  exec(str_c, !!!dots)
}
```

Note the answer you got previously won’t work if the vectors have length >1; using `unlist()` combines them all into a single vector, so they aren’t concatenated together when passed to `str_c()`.